# Customize ORDER BY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have customer name data like this:

```
column_name : Insan, Ir. Cahya, Drs. Setia
```

How can I do `ORDER BY` but the title (education title) is not included?

My expected output (in ascending order):

```
**Cahya, Ir. Insan, Drs. Setia**
```

Note : `Ir` and `Drs` are education titles in Indonesia

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what the data looks like.  An example with rows and columns would help.

Comment: How do you/we know the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include a subquery into the `ORDER BY` and filter the titles there.

In my solution only the 2 titles from your examples would be filtered. I'm pretty sure, that this is not the best solution, but it would work.

```sql
select name
from testtable a
order by (select case
                     when name like 'Ir. %' then substr(name, 5)
                     else
                         case
                             when name like 'Drs. %' then substr(name, 5)
                             else name
                             end
                     end as name
          from testtable t
          where a.id = t.id);
```

I tested this on Postgres with the following setup for my test:

```sql
create table testtable
(
    id bigint,
    name varchar(2000)
);

insert into testtable
values (1, 'Insan, Ir.'),
       (2, 'Cahya'),
       (3, 'Drs. Setia');
```